# mplus - regression including predictors simultaneously vs. not

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, mplus

I'm running an ESEM in MPLUS and I'm wondering if there's a way to run independent regression models with each factors as predictors
so rather than including all factors simultaneously in the model as below:

**1ST VERSION**

'ANALYSIS:
ESTIMATOR=MLR;
ROTATION=TARGET;

Model:
XS BY
X1-X6
Y1-Y6~0
Z1-Z6~0(*1);

YS BY
Y1-Y6
X1-X6~0
Z1-Z6~0 (*1);

ZS BY
Z1-Z6
X1-X6~0
Y1-Y6~0 (*1);

DV1 ON XS YS ZS;'

I want something like this:

**SECOND VERSION:**

'Model:
XS BY
X1-X6
Y1-Y6~0
Z1-Z6~0(*1);

YS BY
Y1-Y6
X1-X6~0
Z1-Z6~0 (*1);

ZS BY
Z1-Z6
X1-X6~0
Y1-Y6~0 (*1);

DV1 ON XS;
DV1 ON YS;
DV1 ON ZS;'

When I run the second one, the output still looks like the predictors (XS, YS, ZS) are included in the same model, but the coefficients do change a little bit...
I'm not sure if this is just the way mplus presents the results (so did I make that difference I wanted?) or if these two models I ran are in fact identical (but why did the results change a bit then?)

Really appreciate any thoughts on this!

Answer (score 0):

In Mplus just like other SEM programs, all of the regression coefficients are estimated simultaneously, so there should be no differences in the results across the two steps.